# Removing the class of a nav li - properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The basic visuals for this question is available at http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap-carousel/inc.carousel/tabbed-slider.html - in case you wanted to take a peek into it.

But here is what's going on.

The HTML & CSS behind that tabbed-carousel is below. (I've just shortened it for brevity purposes. )

```
<style>

    #myCarousel-100 .nav a small {
            display:block;
    }
    #myCarousel-100 .nav {
            background:#eee;
    }
    #myCarousel-100 .nav a {
            border-radius: 0px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">

    <div id="myCarousel-100" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <div class="carousel-inner"><!-- Wrapper for slides -->

            <div class="item active">
                panel 1 content
            </div><!-- End Item -->

            <div class="item active">
                panel 2 content
            </div><!-- End Item -->

        </div><!-- /Wrapper for slides -->


        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel-100" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">panel 1</a></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel-100" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">panel 2</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
</div>
```

Simple enough...

To kick start the show, all we need is to stick the following JS at the footer. 
provided that the boostrap & jQuery is also around, things will work.

```
<script>
        $('#myCarousel-100').carousel({
                interval:   4000 
        });

        var clickEvent = false;
        $('#myCarousel-100').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
                        clickEvent = true;
                        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
        }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
                if(!clickEvent) {
                        var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
                        var current = $('.nav li.active');
                        current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
                        var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
                        if(count == id) {
                                $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
                        }
                }
                clickEvent = false;
        });
</script>
```

That's it.

First of all, where is the problem here? Well, there isn't any.

Well, sort of...

As long as you do not have another tabbed-carousel like that, there is no problem at all.

But, say you wanted to have another instance, with an id myCarousel-200 for example.

Well, you can then just duplicate the code and change every occurrence of `-100` to `-200`, and you will be fine. Right? No.

Everything wwould work except when the onclick event takes place ( on either instances), the clicked-appearance of the last clicked one ***IN THE OTHER CAROUSEL*** will also be effected.

So, for example, you click on say, panel 2 of the first carousel, you will see that panel 2 content will load into the first carousel view port. And the link beneath panel 2 will get the blue highlight. So far so good.

While that is so, if you click on the panel 1 or 2 of ***the other slider***, you will realize that first carousel's last clicked item's blue background will also disappear. 
At that time, the first carousel will have no clicked item appearance at all. 
You surely do not want this behaviour.

Now, why is this happening?

That's happening because, the JS code has calls like this;

```
 $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
```

This code is poorly written because there is no name space that would target nav li elements in the desired carousel  to narrow down the action to that relevant carousel only.

to remedy the situation, I tried the following... but it did not work...

```
$('#myCarousel .nav li').removeClass('active');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code *should* work...are you getting any errors in the console? Can you create a fiddle for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(this).closest('.nav').find('li').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: @Tusher  Thank you... That really does it. There is another issue that puzzles me... What do you think about the part that starts like this; `}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {`. Is the word `slid` a typo for the word `slide`? Is the .bs. a reserved keyword? What are they? And most importantly, do we need that section in the footer js?

Comment: 'slid' is the past form of 'slide', meaning, the function will execute once the slide animation has been finished, hence it will execute once the slide 'slid'.

Comment: Thank you DiH...  I should have tagged this question also as `english`. :) How about .bs.?  Is that also a reserved word? After your explanation, it looks like, I *do* need to have that portionof the code.... If so, what continues to puzzle me is that how is the part in that portion that contains the following code still work? `var current = $('.nav li.active');` Should not we have the `.closest.` trick in there as well? Isn't the .nav loose? See what I mean? What do you think guys?

Comment: "bs" is short for "Bootstrap". It's the namespace Bootstrap uses for its custom JS events, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the solution you accepted does you any good. It's actually doing the opposite - hiding the problem from you.

You're firing changes to both carousels in your script. Instead of for example `$('.nav li')` try `$(this).find('.nav li')`. Once everything is scoped in similar way, you won't need to duplicate code for the next carousels creating multiple `$('#myCarousel-100').on('click'...` blocks.

Comment: Where does the `$(this).find('.nav li')` go?

Comment: That's just an example. Take a look into your code and see that whenever you reference .nav, you reference it document-wide. So what you need to do, is scope ALL of the instances. These are:
('.nav li').removeClass('active'), the two assigned to var count and var current and $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');